# How can you use Windows CMD to save a copy of a file name to a blank text document?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I've been experimenting with Xcopy on my flash drive, which as the reader most likely knows, is a way to transfer multiple file copies very efficiently. During my experimentation, i had a thought. The code i ran(which will be disclosed at the end of the comment) was set to copy files from my desktop, music, photos etc. However, on my desktop was a particularly large file for a game i frequent. When the program got to the games files, it took an extremely long time to copy the files, as the game ran a 3D environment, and i needed this code to run quickly and efficiently. So, my thought was:Is there a way to copy the name of a file(in this case, the name of the game, FTB), have the program copy the name of the file only, then create a text file on the flash drive where the code is being run, then overwrite the name of that document with the copied name?

Here is the code being run, and i am aware that it has some obvious problems, but its being worked on:

```
@echo off
:: variables/min
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y /EXCLUDE:MyExcludes.txt

%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures" "%drive%\all\My pics"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" "%drive%\all\Favorites"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Videos" "%drive%\all\Vids"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" "%drive%\all\Docs"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive" "%drive%\all\Onedrive"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" "%drive%\all\Desktop"
%backupcmd% "%USERPROFILE%\Network" "%drive%\all\Other devices"
copy "Bookmarks.bak" "all"
removedrive D: -L -H -A -W:1000
```

if you need any extra information, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add the large file to the `myexcludes.txt` file so it wont copy
2. just create a new file on your backup drive using something like the following (assuming your file is called mylargefilesname.ext)

   ```
    echo mylargefilesname.ext > "%drive%\location\mylargefilesname.ext"
   ```

------ edit ------

To do this for all .exe files you can exclude *.exe and then use a loop.

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\*.exe"') do echo %%f > "%drive%\all\My pics\%%~nxf"
```

this is looping over the results of `dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\*.exe"`

for each line of the output it will echo the full file path to your new folder using the filename + extension of the file (thats what the `nx` part does)

Comment: In that case, can i splice in code that only does this to .exe\ files, considering its that simple? @FloatingKiwi

Comment: By *this* I mean when the code is run, it copy the files, but when it encounters a .exe file, it then goes through the process described above.

Comment: @MayhemJensen, I've applied an edit with the behaviour I think you're after

Comment: I am exceedingly happy, and you have answered my question exceptionally, but i have on last thing to ask of you @FloatingKiwi. You don't have to as this is exactly what i was looking for, but if you do i would be extremely grateful. Would you mind splicing the code you gave me into the code in the question section?I'm just not sure how to  implement it, and i'm sure once i see how you do it, ill be able to figure it out on my own time later, and let you be.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is resurrecting an old thread, but I've found this code all over the internet (it's been copied a lot) with no clear explanation of the nonsensical `%odrive%` initialization and the non-initialization of `%drive%`.

It doesn't work because they left out some code. Here's how to fix it:

Replace:

```
SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
```

With:

```
SET odrive=%CD%
SET drive=%odrive:~0,2%
```

The first line gets the current directory as `%odrive%` and the second line strips out the first two characters (e.g., `C:`) and assigns them to `%drive%`

Note the script assumes it's being run from the removable drive. So you could simply replace all instances of `%drive%` with `.` and it would work just as well.